# Default create-react-app doesn't load in S3

Tags: amazon-s3, create-react-app

I am having trouble loading a base create-react-app (Version 2.0.3) project in S3. I have a simple S3 bucket with bucket policy of

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

In this bucket I have enabled static website hosting, with Index Document and Error Document: index.html

I then run create-react-app mybasicapp, followed by npm install && npm run build. I then copy the contents of the build folder (not the folder itself) into the s3 bucket. I then hit the link provided under static website hosting and I get a blank page. If I hit url/manifest.json the manifest is displayed in the browser.

I think this issue may have something to do with the requirement that the build folder be served. On my local computer, the index.html can't be loaded by opening the index.html, it has to be served. I have yet to find any resolution for how to make s3 serve this index.html or configure my project differently to avoid this issue. Any advice on how to get S3 to serve this file? Or how to configure my application differently?